# How to prevent printing to stdout from an awk **script** (not from cli)

Tags: awk, scripting, stdout

*[GNU awk v4.2.1 on Archlinux]*

Suppressing `awk`'s default print action to stdout from cli is easy and well documented on UL, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47816105/display-message-when-no-match-found-in-awk). Doing so from a script gives me headaches. Here's the toy script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {FS=","} 
FNR > 1          # skip header
{   
    if ( $1 == $2 ) {
        if ( NR == 4 ) {
            printf("*** Print NR=4 ok. \n")
        } else {
            print > "/dev/null"  # print nothing
        }
    } else {
        printf("=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=%s). \n",NR)
    }
}
```

and toy data:

```
col1 col2
1,3
2,2
aa,aa
3.01,-353.01
4.1,4.1
101,101
hello, hello
asd,koi0
```

along with expected / desired output:

```
=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=2). 
*** Print NR=4 ok. 
=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=5).
=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=8).
=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=9).
```

Instead I get:

```
=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=1). 
1,3
=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=2). 
2,2
aa,aa
*** Print NR=4 ok. 
3.01,-353.01
=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=5). 
4.1,4.1
101,101
hello, hello
=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=8). 
asd,koi0
=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=9).
```

To suppress output to stdout, I tried using:
`getline`,  `{}`, `next`, `printf("")` and even the outlandish `ORS=""; print ""; ORS="\n"` instead of `print > "/dev/null"`. I am obviously doing something very wrong in that frigging script and can not find what ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *only* error is

```
FNR > 1          # skip header
{
```

which should be

```
FNR > 1 {        # skip header
```

A code block with a condition must start on the same line as the condition.

What your original script *actually* does is first

```
FNR > 1
```

This prints all lines from line two onwards (the default action when a condition does not have an associated code block is to print the current record if the condition is true, as if the block had been `{ print }`).

Then it applies the block following that to *each* line (since that block does not have an associated condition).

This is not a peculiarity of GNU `awk`.  All `awk` implementations should act like this.

---

As for the other bits of the script:

```
    } else {
        print > "/dev/null"  # print nothing
    }
```

This could be deleted, leaving

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "," } 

FNR > 1 {   
    if ( $1 == $2 ) {
        if ( NR == 4 )
            printf("*** Print NR=4 ok.\n")
    } else
        printf("=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=%s).\n", NR)
}
```

or,

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "," } 

FNR == 1 { next }

$1 == $2 && NR == 4 { printf("*** Print NR=4 ok.\n") }
$1 != $2            { printf("=== Fields 1 and 2 not equal (NR=%s).\n", NR) }
```

Comment: +1 crystal clear explanation. I did not know that `awk` script syntax required the opening bracket of a conditional block to be on the same line as the conditional expression. That's what `awk` on cli does not reveal to the novice script writer. Thanks.