# Rule with starting { on next line

Tags: awk

I am doing the following, which is repeating `MATCH $0 BEG_ERE` for every line.
Primarily because the starting `{` starts on the next line.  Would this be a bug?

```c
match($0, beg_ere, maggr)
 {
  print "MATCH $0 BEG_ERE"
  print "   " $0
  next
 }
```

Comment: There are plenty of online utilities that you can use to check syntax. Have you used one?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506181/65304

Comment: I understand what is happening.  But what is the reason that `match($0, beg_ere, maggr)` would not consider the consecutive `{` as part of the rule execution.

Comment: `match(...)` has nothing to do with your following `{...}`.

Comment: Then match just runs the command and does nothing.  Then just does the commands in `{ }`.

Comment: Yes, this is no `if(...) {...} else {...}` or `for(...) {...}`.

Comment: This also is the case with `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: "Would this be a bug" in awk? No. "Would this be a bug" in your script? Yes. Please get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to start learning about awk. It'll save you a huge amount of time vs trying to learn awk by posting questions about fundamentals here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a bug - it's a feature.

An awk program consists of a sequence of `rule { action }` pairs where `{ action }` is executed if `rule` evaluates logically TRUE. However, there are two special cases:

1. if `rule` is empty, then `{ action }` is executed for every record i.e. an empty rule is considered TRUE by default
2. if `{ action }` is empty, then the default action equivalent to `{ print $0 }` is assumed.

So your program, *while syntactically correct*, **must be** equivalent to the two separate rule-action pairs

```
match($0, beg_ere, maggr) { print $0 }

1 {
  print "MATCH $0 BEG_ERE"
  print "   " $0
  next
 }
```

See also [How to prevent printing to stdout from an awk **script** (not from cli)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506180/how-to-prevent-printing-to-stdout-from-an-awk-script-not-from-cli)

Comment: Have re-run my awk script and added some printing and it is exactly as you say.  A `print $0` occurs for `match($0, beg_ere, maggr)`.

Comment: @Heime  Please stop using this forum as a course in Awk 101. Read some of the GNU Awk User's Guide: this syntax rule is explained in the third text paragraph of the whole guide, literally before you reach Section 1.1, so clearly a non-bug. As to "Why ?", the answer is "Because !". It avoids additional syntax to deal with constructs like `TRUE block` and `test PRINT`. Note the same construct applies to `function` declarations -- the function block also has to start on the same line.